# How can I show description's value of an enumerated domain in Genexus 9?

Tags: genexus

How can I show description's value of an enumerated domain in Genexus 9?
I need the same functionality than Domain.EnumerationDescription() in Genexus X.

For example: I have a basic enumerated domain "Status"

- **Status**
- value: A - description: Active
- value: I - description: Inactive

I need to set &StatusDescription with the description of Status domain value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GX9 there is no such functionality.

You have to create a procedure to make the conversion.

I don't know of another way.

Answer (score -2):

&StatusDescription = Status.EnumerationDescription()